# How do I pass a translated string to another component in react-jhipster?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, jhipster

I can use the Translation component (from react-jhipster) when i want to add a translated string in a component:

```
<p><Translation contentKey="my.key">Some text</Translation></p>
```

But if I want to pass a translated string to another component, how would I do that? Like:

```
<MyComponent text={{translate("my.key")}} />
```

Comment: tell us more info about your Translation component - is it from any library?

Comment: It's from react-jhipster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in comment, you are using react-jhipster library.

From what i got, you can import `translate (contentKey: string, interpolate?: any, children?: string)` function from `react-jhipster`.

Try: `import {translate} from 'react-jhipster'`

> Source: https://github.com/jhipster/react-jhipster/blob/master/src/language/translate.tsx

---

And you dont need always to pass it like props, you can also use it in component's body.

Comment: I know this is old, but I have what I thought was the same question except your answer isn't the solution for me. I'm already importing the translation component from react-jhipster. I'd like to know if it's possible to use a translated string as a prop in another component. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Ok I figured out the right way to do this! Import the translation component: `import { Translate as Trans, translate } from 'react-jhipster';` Then you can use the Trans component with `contentKey` like normal, but also you can use the translate method on some other component: `<OpeningComponentTag className="some-class" propToTranslate={translate('path.to.json.translation.string')}>` Hope this helps someone else scratching their head :)